# C# updating backgroundworker progress from separate class

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am trying to run a function in a different class than the dispatcher through a backgroundworker and have it update the progress on every iteration. I am getting no errors and the backgroundworker is functioning properly, but my textbox never updates...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(workerDoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(workerProgressChanged);
    }

    private void myButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void workerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        yv_usfm.convert(worker);
    }

    void workerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myTextBox.Text = "some text";
    }

}

public class yv_usfm
{
    public static void convert(BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (i < 100)
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're thinking of update a `BackgroundWorker`'s progress from a *different* class then you've misunderstood what a `BackgroundWorker` is for.  I'd suggest you use the a `Task<T>` or the thread pool.

Comment: I just copied and ran your code and it works just fine for me...

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why my textbox is not updating

Comment: Err sorry I just realized you are using WPF. It works fine in a Windows Form but not a WPF Window

Comment: Oops sorry again. It is working for me in WPF as well...dang it!

Comment: I figured it out, I am using htmlagilitypack to download a webpage, it was working the whole time, but I justs didnt wait long enough for it to finish one iteration (downloading the page source take a little while) before adding the new text...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This:

```
void DoWork(...)
{
    YourMethod();
}

void YourMethod()
{
    if(yourControl.InvokeRequired)
        yourControl.Invoke((Action)(() => YourMethod()));
    else
    {
        //Access controls
    }
}
```

Hope This help.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` is called on the UI thread. You shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: @George I just want to help that guy and i think my answer helps that guy.

Comment: @George Please read answer by Charles Mager below and comment by that guy.

Comment: I don't understand; In the example in the question there is no Invoke required as the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event is triggered on the UI thread. Charles Mager's answer was the same as my answer and irrelevant since the question was edited/updated. This answer would over-complicate the scenario needlessly would it not? Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: It is ok @George actually i was surprised for your down vote on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you say the `BackgroundWorker` is functioning properly?  I see no call to `worker.RunWorkerAsync()`, and without that it will never start.

Comment: my bad, I have it in my code, I justs didnt put in on stack overflow --__-

Answer (score 0):

You're not starting the worker!

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: I do have it in my code, I just idiotically forgot to include it in my stackoverflow post...edited

Comment: I made my own quick project copying and pasting your code and once I'd added `RunWorkerAsync()` the text box updated just fine. Are there any other differences between your sample code here and the project you're working on?

Comment: In my project code I actually have `worker.RunWorkerAsync();` in a button click, I updated my post

Comment: I've just moved `RunWorkerAsync()` into a button click event and when I click the button the textbox still updates. Have you tried copying your code in the question into a new plain WPF project to isolate the problem?